# Wait for specific stage to complete in Jenkins parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have stages running in parallel. Each stage has sub-stages.

```
stage("Prepare VMs") {
  parallel {
    stage("Prepare Database VM") {
      stage("Install Database") {...}
      stage("Upgrade Database") {...}
    }
    stage("Prepare Server VM") {
      stage("Install Server") {...}
      stage("Start Server") {...}
    }
    stage("Prepare Client VM") {
      stage("Install Client") {...}
    }
  }
}
```

As the above is now, the sub-stages of each stage run sequentially, but can run in parallel with the other stage.

What I want is for *Start Server* to wait until *Upgrade Database* finish. In other words, *Install Server* can run while *Install Database* or *Upgrade Database* run, but *Start Server* has to wait for *Upgrade Database* to finish. Is this possible?

My initial approach was to use an `AtomicBoolean`, but my company's Jenkins does not permit it.

```
final AtomicBoolean DATABASE_READY = new AtomicBoolean(false);

stage("Prepare VMs") {
  parallel {
    stage("Prepare Database VM") {
      stage("Install Database") {...}
      // At the end of the stage, it sets DATABASE_READY to true.
      stage("Upgrade Database") {...}
    }
    stage("Prepare Server VM") {
      stage("Install Server") {...}
      // Waits for DATABASE_READY.
      stage("Start Server") {...}
    }
    stage("Prepare Client VM") {
      stage("Install Client") {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Nor can I use `CountDownLatch` or similar.

Comment: Why can't you simply move `"Start Server"` out from the parallel block?

Comment: You would need to do some kind of `async/wait` instead of `parallel`.

Comment: @ycr I see what you mean. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let the continuous stages take care of that for you.

```
parallel {
 stage("Prepare VMs") {
  stages {
   stage("Prepare VMs 1") {
    parallel {
     stage("Prepare Database VM") {
      stage("Install Database") {...}
     }
     stage("Prepare Server VM") {
      stage("Install Server") {...}
     }
    }
   }
   stage("Prepare VMs 2") {
   // This will only run when the previous group has finished.
   parallel {
    stage("Prepare Database VM") {
      stage("Upgrade Database") {...}
    }
    stage("Prepare Server VM") {
      stage("Start Server") {...}
    }
   }
  }
 }
 stage("Prepare Client VM")
      stage("Install Client") {...}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would apply, but I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't understand why you can't use sequential stages for your use case :) But anyway here is how you can achieve this with lockable resources. You can read more on the plugin [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) and [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/).

#### Explanation

The lockable resource plugin allows you to create Global locks and let the pipeline acquire them as needed.

If you take the following pipeline.  Lock `lock ('db_setup_lock')` within the `Options` block allows you to acquire the lock `db_setup_lock` for both `Install Database` and `Upgrade Database` stages, and this lock will only be released upon completion of both `Stages`. Assuming `Install Server` will take some time to run there is no possibility of `Start Server` acquiring the same lock before `Prepare Database VM`. Hence `Start Server` has to wait until the lock is released by the `Prepare Database VM` stages.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Prepare VMs") {
            parallel {
                stage("Prepare Database VM") {
                    options {
                       lock ('db_setup_lock')
                    }
                    stages {
                        stage("Install Database") {
                            steps {
                                echo "Install Database"
                                sleep 15
                                }
                            }
                        stage("Upgrade Database") {
                            steps {
                                echo "Upgrade Database start"
                                sleep 30
                                echo "Upgrade Database End"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage("Prepare Server VM") {
                    stages {
                        stage("Install Server") {
                            steps {
                                echo "Install Server"
                                sleep 15
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Start Server") {
                             steps {
                                lock('db_setup_lock') {
                                    echo "Starting Server"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How will this guarantee that *Upgrade Database* is executed before *Start Server*?

Comment: @Oliver I realized there could be race conditions in the previous pipeline. Please check the slightly modified Pipeline and the explanation. Hope it helps.